# How install view model in fragmentComponent with Hilt injection?

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-hilt

I want scope ViewModel and it's dependencies by Fragment not activity,

```
interface MarsRepository {
    suspend fun getProperties(): List<Mars>
}



@Module
@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
class MarsRepositoryModule {
    
    @Provides
    fun bindRemoteMarsDataSource(): MarsRepository{
        return RemoteMarsStorageImp()
    }
}



class MarsViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(private val repository: MarsRepository): ViewModel()



@AndroidEntryPoint
class MarsFragment: Fragment() {
    
    val viewModel by viewModels<MarsViewModel>()
}
```

But I got this

```
/app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/com/Sample/bestcase/DevByteApplication_HiltComponents.java:111: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.Sample.domain.repository.MarsRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements DevByteApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      javax.inject.Provider<com.Sample.domain.repository.MarsRepository> is injected at
          com.Sample.bestcase.features.mars.MarsViewModel_AssistedFactory(repository)
      com.Sample.bestcase.features.mars.MarsViewModel_AssistedFactory is injected at
          com.Sample.bestcase.features.mars.MarsViewModel_HiltModule.bind(factory)
      java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>> is injected at
          androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelFactoryModules.ActivityModule.provideFactory(…, viewModelFactories)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory java.util.Set<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultViewModelFactories.ActivityEntryPoint.getActivityViewModelFactory() [com.Sample.bestcase.DevByteApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.Sample.bestcase.DevByteApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.Sample.bestcase.DevByteApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityC]
  The following other entry points also depend on it:
      dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultViewModelFactories.FragmentEntryPoint.getFragmentViewModelFactory() [com.Sample.bestcase.DevByteApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.Sample.bestcase.DevByteApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.Sample.bestcase.DevByteApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityC → com.Sample.bestcase.DevByteApplication_HiltComponents.FragmentC]
```

It just works if installed by ActivityComponent

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
class MarsRepositoryModule { 
    @Provides
    fun bindRemoteMarsDataSource(): MarsRepository{
        return RemoteMarsStorageImp()
    }
}
```

As I track the code It uses DefaultActivityViewModelFactory instead of DefaultFragmentViewModelFactory

```
 /**
     * Hilt Modules for providing the activity level ViewModelFactory
     */
    @Module
    @InstallIn(ActivityComponent.class)
    public abstract static class ActivityModule {

        @NonNull
        @Multibinds
        abstract Map<String, ViewModelAssistedFactory<? extends ViewModel>> viewModelFactoriesMap();

        @Provides
        @IntoSet
        @NonNull
        @DefaultActivityViewModelFactory
        static ViewModelProvider.Factory provideFactory(
                @NonNull Activity activity,
                @NonNull Application application,
                @NonNull Map<String, Provider<ViewModelAssistedFactory<? extends ViewModel>>>
                        viewModelFactories) {
            // Hilt guarantees concrete activity is a subclass of ComponentActivity.
            SavedStateRegistryOwner owner = (ComponentActivity) activity;
            Bundle defaultArgs = activity.getIntent() != null
                    ? activity.getIntent().getExtras() : null;
            SavedStateViewModelFactory delegate =
                    new SavedStateViewModelFactory(application, owner, defaultArgs);
            return new HiltViewModelFactory(owner, defaultArgs, delegate, viewModelFactories);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Hilt Modules for providing the fragment level ViewModelFactory
     */
    @Module
    @InstallIn(FragmentComponent.class)
    public static final class FragmentModule {

        @Provides
        @IntoSet
        @NonNull
        @DefaultFragmentViewModelFactory
        static ViewModelProvider.Factory provideFactory(
                @NonNull Fragment fragment,
                @NonNull Application application,
                @NonNull Map<String, Provider<ViewModelAssistedFactory<? extends ViewModel>>>
                        viewModelFactories) {
            Bundle defaultArgs = fragment.getArguments();
            SavedStateViewModelFactory delegate =
                    new SavedStateViewModelFactory(application, fragment, defaultArgs);
            return new HiltViewModelFactory(fragment, defaultArgs, delegate, viewModelFactories);
        }

        private FragmentModule() {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The viewmodel is already scoped by its fragment. What the compiler tries to tell you is, that you are trying to inject your `repository` inside a component, that outlives the fragment.

As it says in the component section [here](https://dagger.dev/hilt/components):

> Each component is responsible for injecting a different type of Android class. This is shown in the table below:
> [image]

In order to inject a dependency in a viewmodel, it has to be at least `ActivityRetainedScoped`

---

### Fix

Change `FragmentComponent::class` with `ActivityRetainedComponent::class` or `SingletonComponent::class`

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class) // or at least ActivityRetainedComponent
class MarsRepositoryModule { 
    @Provides
    fun bindRemoteMarsDataSource(): MarsRepository{
        return RemoteMarsStorageImp()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's already working with ActivityComponent, but I want scop ViewModel to fragment not activity!!.
Each fragment has its own ViewModel instance, not a shared instance.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "I want to scope ViewModel to fragment not activity". The viewmodel ALREADY IS scoped to the fragment. When you write `by viewModels<T>()` your viewmodel is scoped to the corresponding FRAGMENT. This has NOTHING to do with how you scope your repository inside your viewmodel. If you want your viewmodel to be activity scoped, then you write `by activityViewModel()`

Comment: I meant the repository scoped to fragment the same as ViewModel.
If it's scoped by fragment then Why Does it use DefaultActivityViewModelFactory for providing the viewmodel?